# How do I prevent WiFi cycling between connected and disconnected?

Tags: wireless, disconnect

My friend has a Acer Aspire 5733Z-4851 it keeps disconnecting and connecting to his wifi but his hard wire will run just fine. Any suggestions?

All the codes:

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          12798  0
rfcomm                 46619  0
bnep                   18140  2
bluetooth             209199  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32688  0
ppdev                  17073  0
lp                     17759  0
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
binfmt_misc            17500  1
ums_realtek            17949  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77876  1
uas                    17844  0
coretemp               13400  0
snd_hda_intel          33491  4
snd_hda_codec         134212  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96580  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               76749  0
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61521  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
arc4                   12529  2
snd_seq_device         14497  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
psmouse                95552  0
ath9k                 131308  0
tg3                   148780  0
snd                    78734  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
microcode              22803  0
mac80211              539908  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           14055  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              395218  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    23827  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
i915                  520629  3
soundcore              15047  1 snd
serio_raw              13215  0
cfg80211              206566  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
intel_ips              18049  0
lpc_ich                17061  0
drm_kms_helper         46784  1 i915
drm                   275528  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
mei                    40690  0
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
joydev                 17457  0
acer_wmi               32453  0
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
mxm_wmi                12979  0
mac_hid                13205  0
wmi                    19070  2 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  19335  2 i915,acer_wmi
usb_storage            48838  1 ums_realtek
```

`sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network              
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:70:f4:9a:35:b6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 duplex=half firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 memory:d3400000-d340ffff[/QUOTE][QUOTE]*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 68:a3:c4:eb:60:7d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.168 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d2400000-d240ffff)
```

Comment: I think there are ongoing problems with Atheros wireless products. See eg. [Random disconnects with an Atheros AR5008](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85973/random-disconnects-with-an-atheros-ar5008).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with atheros wi-fi and acer_wmi module.

Try black listing `acer_wmi`

by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and pasting the below text in:

`echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi`

You can then reboot or enter `sudo rmmod acer-wmi`

If this doesn't work, and you want to revert back,

remove `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi` (by clicking on your Home Folder, clicking on 'File System' under 'Computer' on the left pane, double-clicking on etc and then modprobe.d and deleting the file 'blacklist-acer-wmi')