# Serious problem with WIFI device and driver

Tags: wireless, ath9k

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[Solved]Wireless cycling between connected and disconnected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225613/solvedwireless-cycling-between-connected-and-disconnected)

I am running a laptop powered by Acer

```
Model: Acer Aspire 4250
Processor: E450 APU
Ram: 2GB
Wireless :  Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
Wifi driver: ath9k
```

Problem is after 30min of start WIFI device fails to connect. It shows password is not match, also it takes too much processor. After a restart everything works fine but same things happen after 5 min. 
dmesg shows os fails to wake up wifi adapter. Is it a hardware problem or software?

Used OS:
ubuntu 11.10, 12.04, 12.10, Mint 12, windows 7

This problem start after 2/3 days of fresh installation(no problem within 2 days). But i didn't get any problem with windows7.

I tried **no encryption** option with ath9k driver. Also tried wicd-network-manager instead of gnome-network-manager

Comment: @Web-E That solution didn't work for me, It broke my display.