# Wifi problems Acer Aspire M3 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, acer

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Acer Aspire Timeline Ultra M3-481T-53314G52Mass
and everything works fine except the wifi. The connection always drops down after a few Minutes. I saw some threads with similar questions, but nothing really helps me.
Would be great to get an answer here.

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[Solved\]Wireless cycling between connected and disconnected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225613/solvedwireless-cycling-between-connected-and-disconnected). If that doesn't help provide hardware details same as in the linked question

Answer (score 0):

i had loads of trouble with all sorts of methods not working.

Get to a wired connection,

Terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

after installing i removed the wired connection and rebooted the system.

worked like a charm