# Wireless don't show in Acer Aspire E1-470

Tags: 12.04, acer

I hv problem in my acer laptop. It's don't show wireless network in my AcerE1-470. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the first icon in unity (menu panel on left hand side)
2. Type **Additional Driver**
3. Run the application.
4. If everything goes well then you might be able to see your wireless card in the application.
5. Select you card and then click on the **Activate** button at the right hand bottom side.
6. Restart and enjoy wireless.

For more info click below:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/

Comment: Thz Kishlay, When i click additional driver it's don't show anything. I mean it's completely blank there nothing to Activate anything. I need 10 repu to upload img if not i can show u with img.

Comment: 1. Do you get an error when you start Ubuntu (i.e your PC) like goto website (example:http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware)?

2. Do you see the wireless not activated or something like this when you click the wifi drop-menu in the top panel?

Comment: 1. I don't get any error in PC start.
2. when i click wifi drop-menu i see wireless tap in network manager and i think wireless not activate. I'm weired in ur question. And really appreciate for your reply. TouchPad also doesn't work in my PC. Everything work perfect in Window 8. :D

Comment: when i scan network i don't see wlan0 in my PC. :D

Comment: Do you see eth1 and eth2?

Comment: Even my wireless does not work on wlan0 it works on eth2

Comment: Please check http://askubuntu.com/questions/231686/wifi-problems-acer-aspire-m3-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1

Comment: Yeah i ald tried with linux-firmware-nonfree but still not working :D

Comment: I will show u some result when i run sudo lshw -C network 

 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
 configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
 *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
configuration: latency=0

Comment: Since you have AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter please try the below link

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044

Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thx Kishlay, now it's work. I'm really appreciate ur answer and i more question about TouchPad. I feel touchpad doesn't work very well. Is there any way to work as normal.

Comment: That's great..

If this helped then please mark the answer useful for others to see. Sorry I haven't use touchpad on Ubuntu and I don't have any idea about it. But surely if I find something useful I will post it here in comments