# 12.10 wireless keeps disconnecting -

Tags: wireless

I'm writing this on a wired connection because the wireless keeps disconnecting. Has anyone else had this problem and is there a fix? Here's my network details:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 09
       serial: b8:88:e3:6d:d7:f5
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 ip=192.168.1.78 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0104000-c0104fff memory:c0100000-c0103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 50:b7:c3:56:a3:4f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-27-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0000000-c007ffff memory:c0080000-c008ffff
```

The wireless disconnects and then never reconnects, but attempts to do so constantly.

Edit: The computer is a Samsung 350V5C.

lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 46620  0 
parport_pc             32689  0 
bnep                   18141  2 
ppdev                  17074  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32049  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    78147  1 
uvcvideo               76750  0 
videobuf2_core         32852  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120310  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12861  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13405  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
arc4                   12530  2 
ath3k                  12919  0 
btusb                  22475  0 
rts5139               356200  0 
ath9k                 131317  0 
mac80211              540032  1 ath9k
bluetooth             209249  12 rfcomm,bnep,ath3k,btusb
joydev                 17458  0 
snd_hda_intel          33492  3 
ath9k_common           14056  1 ath9k
i915                  520615  4 
ath9k_hw              395357  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_hda_codec         134213  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
coretemp               13401  0 
drm_kms_helper         49113  1 i915
kvm_intel             132760  0 
snd_hwdep              17699  1 snd_hda_codec
drm                   288721  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm                96668  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
kvm                   414071  1 kvm_intel
ath                    23828  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
snd_seq_midi           13325  0 
snd_rawmidi            30513  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    13221  0 
aesni_intel            51038  0 
cryptd                 20404  2 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_seq                61555  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cfg80211              206797  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
snd_timer              29426  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
lp                     17760  0 
samsung_laptop         14533  0 
parport                46346  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
snd                    78921  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                95595  0 
aes_x86_64             17256  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           13414  1 i915
microcode              22804  0 
mac_hid                13206  0 
soundcore              15048  1 snd
video                  19391  2 i915,samsung_laptop
snd_page_alloc         18485  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mei                    40691  0 
wmi                    19071  0 
lpc_ich                17062  0 
serio_raw              13216  0 
hid_generic            12541  0 
usbhid                 46987  0 
hid                   100411  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ahci                   25721  2 
libahci                31192  1 ahci
r8169                  61651  0
```

Comment: You can have a look here [How do I prevent WiFi cycling between connected and disconnected?](http://askubuntu.com/q/225613). To check whether you have that conflicting module use `lsmod | grep acer`

Comment: Thanks for that, but it looks like I don't have the conflicting module (acer_wmi). I've added the lsmod details to this post if it helps.

Comment: 2.4GHz cordless phones can kill WiFi connections with no debug trace that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've turned off anything that transmits at 2.4GHz and it still disconnects.